# How to pass empty textbox data as parameter to stored procedure in oracle using .NET

Tags: c#, oracle

I am a developing an application with different text boxs that I am passing to oracle stored procedure using ASP.NET ( c# ). For each textbox there is a property in a class file. When I pass empty textbox it is throwing an error. This is because that a varchar2 field in oracle is not accepting "null".

```
      Private string _fristName;

      public string FirstName 
      {
           get { return _fristName; }
           set { _fristName= value; }
      }
```

Which is best practice for making _fristName as string.empty or "" ?

Comment: It's better to use `string.Empty` rather than `""`.  After .Net 2.0, they are exactly the same.  However, as far as readability is concerned, most programmers would agree that `string.Empty` is more pleasant to read.

Answer (score 5):

In your class' initialization, just set your private variable to a default value of `String.Empty`.

```
Private string _fristName = String.Empty;
```

Getting it will return an empty string, not null; setting it will change the value to whatever.

You could also do this:

```
  Private string _fristName;

  public string FirstName 
  {
       get { return _fristName ?? String.Empty; }
       set { _fristName= value; }
  }
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Took suggestion from @Marc in the comments.  Changed the comparison to use the `??` operator.  Thanks @Marc!

Comment: Or more tersely `get { return _firstName ?? ""; }`

Comment: Oooh, yeah -- I always forget about `??`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before setting the value of the parameter in the stored procedure, check for null.  This could be put in a common function.  Note this is for sql server, but a similiar function could be done for Oracle.  Also, if the column can't take a null, then instead of DBNull.Value, maybe a default is used (String.Empty for strings, etc.).

```
IDbDataParameter parameter = new SqlParameter(ParameterName, DatabaseFieldType);

parameter.Value = (value== null ? DBNull.Value : value);
```